# Autohotkey Mouse Click Every 45 Minutes

Tags: macros, autohotkey, game-development

I'm trying to make autohotkey click a certain screen region, every 45 minutes.  I've come up with this, but it seems not to respond correctly.
Can anyone offer suggestions?

```
Loop,99
{
  MouseClick, left,  392,  735
  Sleep 2700000
}
Return
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say doesn't respond correctly, can you be more specific? Is your loop not working, is the timer giving you issues or is the mouseclick not working. In some browsers, I've noticed that you might need to play around with mouseclicking (there are various ways to simulate a mouseclick [up to sending raw code] and there are timers to set the click time).

If you want the loop to indeed only run 99 times, you might need to add a counter in my example, but your objective cab be done with the settimer command.

```
SetTimer, MyMouseClick, 2700000 ; Run  every 2700 seconds
Return

MyMouseClick:
    MouseClick, left, 392, 735
Return
```

Alternative with 99 limit.

```
MyCounter := 0
SetTimer, MyMouseClick, 2700000 ; Run  every 2700 seconds
Return

MyMouseClick:
    MyCounter++
    MouseClick, left, 392, 735
    If (MyCounter = 100)
         SetTimer, MyMouseClick, Off
Return
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to click a fixed screen coordiate, than make sure you are using `CoordMode, Mouse, Screen`. A script starts with a default of `Relative`.
[CoordMode](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/CoordMode.htm)

```
  CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
  Loop, 99
  {
    MouseClick, left, 42, 34
    Sleep 2000
  }
Return

F12::ExitApp
```